# Array Broadcasting with Two 2D Arrays (Python)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, array-broadcasting

I have the two following arrays:

A - of shape **DxN**

B - of shape **NxD**

I'm trying to take an element-wise multiplication of A and B and ultimately produce a **NxDxD** array, using array broadcasting.

I'm a bit lost on how to start. I've tried a few things, but none of my attempts have gotten anywhere. Perhaps something like this just isn't possible?

For some context, I'm relatively new to Python and am trying to write my own implementation of a `ML algorithm`. My current approach would involve doing this calculation.

Comment: The `dot` sum of products can be produced with `(A[:,None,:]*B.T[None,:,:]).sum(axis=-1)`.  That makes the (D,D,N) array and then sums.  It's not as fast/direct as the `dot`, but it's a good idea to understand what it's doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using numpy all you gotta do is:

```
result = numpy.dot(A, B)
```

If you get an error, something like dimensions not aligned, you have to transform the matrix by:

```
result = numpy.dot(A, B.T)
```

this should do the job

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[2, 3],
            [4, 3],
            [2, 4]])

b = np.array([[2, 3, 4],
              [3, 4, 5]])

print(np.dot(a, b).shape)
```

returns (3, 3)

Comment: Edit: Would this be the equivalent of making a NxDxD matrix and summing over N to produce a DxD matrix?

Comment: I edited the answer, I hope I understood correctly...

Comment: Thank you, your answer ended up working out! There originally was no need for me to make a NxDxD matrix, just a DxD would work. Sorry for the poorly worded question.